# Trying to center image and lens with jQuery cloudzoom

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

That's basically it. I have a demo up [here](http://emmerich-and-sons2462.myshopify.com/products/book-and-this-is-what-i-saw).

I have been going nuts for about an hour on this and I think it's going to take some hacking on the cloudzoom file itself, but I'm not sure. CSS changes appear to be getting me exactly nowhere.

If you hover over the large image you will see what I am talking about any suggestions are super appreciated at this point.

Comment: I'm not sure about what are you trying to do yet.

Comment: I need images and the zoom lens that is used for the actual zooming to be centered. Images will be different sizes and aspect ratios most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying this css:

```
#product-image #wrap{position:relative;width:225px;margin:0 auto;}
#product-image #wrap a{position:relative;}
#product-image #wrap a img{}
.mousetrap{}
```

Basically, set the wrapper to match the image size, then center it. I removed all the extra margin and positioning css and it seems to work.

---

Ok, since you are using different width images, I went ahead and modified the code. Bascially it adds a left margin minus the left border width of the image. This change was at line 282, with one line added before it:

```
cm = (parseInt(sImg.css('margin-left'),10) - parseInt(sImg.css('border-left-width'),10)) + 'px';

// Attach mouse, initially invisible to prevent first frame glitch
lens = jWin.append(format("<div class = 'cloud-zoom-lens' style='display:none;z-index:98;position:absolute;width:%0px;height:%1px;margin-left:%2'></div>", cw, ch, cm)).find(':last');
```

I posted the full code in the [jsFiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/zGjgy/).

I tested it locally, but I didn't have different image widths to work with, so I can't tell if it will work properly in all cases on your site.

To make it work, basically take the code posted in the jsFiddle and replace your current "js_cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js" file with it.

Comment: Unfortunately that only work if all images are the same size and aspect ratio. This is an e-com situation and that tends to be rarely the case. I think it's going to take changes to the plugin.

Comment: Honestly, if that plugin is causing that much trouble, try another one: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/02/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-stunning-image-zoom-effects.html

Comment: Been there. This is the only one I can find that supports multiple images out of the box. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That's hot! That gets me so close. It takes into account the very first image in the loop, but not the second, but I think it at least moves over enough to work in 99% of all cases they will have. I can't thank you enough fudgey. This was killing me. I have updated with your additional line on the live demo site and you can have a look: http://emmerich-and-sons2462.myshopify.com/collections/all/products/book-and-this-is-what-i-saw

Comment: I spent a great deal of time shopping for a zoom plug-in that supported multiple image files and this was truly the only one I could come up with that didn't need severe hacking to get the desired end result. With your generous help I think this will finally fit the bill.

Comment: To me the second image is exactly the same as the first. But the third image is a straight on view of the book cover and I do notice that that one is shifted a bit to the left. I think it should be centered using CSS `margin: 0 auto` or `text-align: center` on the image - hopefully that doesn't mess up the hack LOL. And I'm glad I could help :)